# Estilizar mensagem de retorno

Tags: css

Gostaria de estilizar as mensagens de retorno de um cadastro de *Newsletter* que tenho em meu site, as tentativas que fiz não deram o resultado esperado e creio que a falta de conhecimento no assunto tem atrapalhado muito.

O que tenho hoje é isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#newsletter-form").submit(function(){

        var valor = $("input[name=newsletter]").val(); 

        if (valor != "" ) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "newsletter.php",
            data: $("#newsletter").serialize(),
            dataType: "json",

            success: function(msg){
                $("#Resposta").removeClass('sucesso');
                $("#Resposta").addClass(msg.status);
                $("#Resposta").html(msg.message);

            },
            error: function(){
                $("#Resposta").removeClass('erro');
                $("#Resposta").addClass('erro');
                $("#Resposta").html(msg.message);
            }
        });
        return false;   
        }   
    });
});
```

A mensagem de sucesso em uma `div` verde e a de erro em uma vermelha e que ambas sumissem depois de um período, isso já consegui fazer, mas não sei se de forma correta.

A definição das mensagens estão assim no meu `.php`:

```
<?php

 require_once('Connections/conexao.php');

// Recebendo o array com os ID´S
$email = $_POST['newsletter'];  

//response array with status code and message
$response_array = array();

// Realiza verificação se já existe e-mail gravado no banco
mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
$sql = "SELECT email FROM newsletter WHERE email = '$email'";
$busca = mysql_query($sql,$conexao);
$linhas = mysql_num_rows($busca);

if ( $linhas > 0 ){
    //set the response
    $response_array['status'] = 'erro';
    $response_array['message'] = '<p style="color:#f25824">E-mail já cadastrado em nossa base</p>';

} else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO newsletter (email, status ) VALUES ('$email', 1)";
    mysql_select_db($database_conexao, $conexao);
    $sql = mysql_query($sql); 

    if ($sql) {
        $response_array['status'] = 'sucesso';
        $response_array['message'] = '<p style="color:#669900">Você se inscreveu com sucesso para a nossa newsletter.</p>';         

    } else {
        $response_array['status'] = 'erro';
        $response_array['message'] = '<p style="color:#f25824">O seu endereço de email não pode ser subscrito porque ocorreu um erro no servidor. Por favor, tente novamente mais tarde.</p>';                      
    }       

}

echo json_encode($response_array);

?>
```

O resultado de minha última tentativa pode ser vista aqui, ao cadastrar um e-mail para newsletter:

[Insiram um e-mail como por exemplo: web@web.com](http://www.moveissaobento.com.br/msb/index.php)

Comment: Eu utilizo uma library pronta para notificações rápidas chamada Toastr by CodeSeven, recomendo e serviria exatamente para o seu propósito. [http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/]´, vou colocar um código de exemplo como resposta de como eu a utilizo.

Comment: Olá @Rafael Withoeft, obrigado pela dica mas a página está com erro.

Comment: Desculpe, aqui carregou normalmente... de qualquer forma coloquei um exemplo a sua disposição caso ache interessante.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este é um exemplo de uma função javascript que utilizo para mandar as mensagens
Library Toastr http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/

```
function sendToastr(mensagem, tipo) {
    toastr.options = {
        'closeButton': true,
        'debug': false,
        'progressBar': true,
        'positionClass': 'toast-top-full-width text-center',
        'onclick': null,
        'showDuration': '400',
        'hideDuration': '1000',
        'timeOut': '5000',
        'extendedTimeOut': '1000',
        'showEasing': 'swing',
        'hideEasing': 'linear',
        'showMethod': 'fadeIn',
        'hideMethod': 'fadeOut'
    };
    if (tipo == "success") {
        toastr.success(mensagem);
    } else if (tipo == "error") {
        toastr.error(mensagem);
    } else if (tipo == "info") {
        toastr.info(mensagem);
    }

}
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
sendToastr('CNPJ Inválido', 'error');
```

Lembrando que o javascript da library precisa estar carregado.

Comment: Se por algum acaso os comentários feitos na pergunta forem apagados, essa resposta perde todo o sentido. Nem é mencionada qual *library* esta sendo usada, nem explicações e referências de como utiliza-la Tenha em mente que o importante nessa comunidade são as perguntas e as **respostas**, não os comentários.

Comment: Acabei de editar e mencionar a library e seu link.

Comment: Olá @Rafael Withoeft, teria como dar um exemplo de como recuperar as mensagens de erro ou acerto do meu .php

Comment: @adventistapr Desculpe mas que tipos de erros você quis dizer? Se forem do PHP você pode utilizar `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, caso seja de validação do seu código (ex: e-mail) teria que ser de outra maneira.... poderia ser mais específico?

Comment: Utilizei a dica do @Rafael Withoeft, ainda estou aprendendo, mas a dica foi muito interessante.

Answer (score 0):

Se entendi bem, conheço o Flavr. É ótimo, mostra uma caixa de alerta em popup, e também tem  botões de confirmação e prompt, como se fosse funções nativas do javascript "alert", "confirm" e "prompt", porém personalizadas no estilo de design Flat. O único problema que tem é que é pago, custa 6 dolares.

Caso queira dar uma olhada: `http://dierg.com/flavr/`

Espero ter ajudado!

Comment: Obrigado @Haroldo Torres, vou dar uma olhada, mesmo sendo pago pode ser uma solução futura.